# ASP.Net Web API : adding appSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am migrating a web service from WCF service to ASP.Net Web API. When I try to add the following section to web.config, I get a page with error "Internal Server Error" when I try to run the application locally

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="production" />
    <add key="CacheEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

When I remove this section, the error goes away.
Can you please tell me how to add appSettings to a Web API project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `appSettings` needs to to into the Web.config under the `configuration` element as per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) docs:

```
<configuration>
      <appSettings />
</configuration>
```

1. Make sure it's in the right element
2. Make sure there isn't already an existing `appSettings` tag

Otherwise, you would need to pass on the exact error message.

Comment: appSettings is under configuration and there is no duplication

Comment: Is it in the correct Web.config? There is a Web.config in the root and a Web.config in the views folder

Comment: Ah! I didnt know that..I had tried on the one in the root and got the error. now when I tried on the one inside Views, I didnt get the error..but then, I could access the variables either.. System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Setting] returned null. (Setting is the variable holding the key)

Comment: Are you *sure* there is no existing appSettings in the root Web.config, because by default MVC has one :)

Answer (score 16):

The following can be a guide on how to do it, verify that your appSettings are inside configuration

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Key" value="Value"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

To get the values of the key from the application you can do

```
textBox1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"];
```